# Подключение модулю на уровень выше

Tags: python, модули

[image: директория]

в файл `test_responseParser.py` я пытаюсь импортировать файл `responseParser.py` :

```
from .. import responseParser
```

но возникает ошибка :

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Не понимаю почему ведь две точки означают на один уровень выше, что нет так?

Comment: как запускаете? кнопкой в IDE? покажите, пожалуста, настройки или команду запуска в терминале.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть вы пытаетесь импортировать объект responseParser из файла `responseParser.py`. В этом случае вам нужно явно указать этот файл: `from .responseParser import responseParser`.
Альтернативой может быть добавление файла `__init__.py` в разделе с файлом `responseParser.py`. В нем должно быть следующее: `from responseParser import responseParser`.